# Eleventy + Liquid object in PairShortcodes

Tags: object, liquid, shortcode, eleventy

I am using liquid and eleventy — I want to pass an object to my shortcode, but I am getting an error.

With nunjunks you could do something like...

```js
// .eleventy.js

config.addPairedShortcode('alert', function(content, options = {}) {
  const { variant = 'primary' } = options;
  return `<div class="alert alert-${variant}" role="alert">${content}</div>
});
```

I could then pass the alert in my template as

```
{# index.njk #}

{% alert { variant: 'danger' } %}
  A danger alert
{% endalert %}
```

Using this shortcode works with my liquid templates, I'm just not able to pass an object to the shortcode as I can with `njk` templates.

I'm not sure if I would then just have to something like:

```js
function(content, variant)
```

then in my liquid template pass `{% alert "danger" %}` — I was hoping to have an object as I plan to have quite a few options, it would make it difficult to see what options are set in my templates.

Here is the error I am getting with the shortcode in my liquid templates:

```sh
[dev:11ty  ] `TemplateContentRenderError` was thrown
[dev:11ty  ] > invalid syntax at line 1 col 1:
[dev:11ty  ]
[dev:11ty  ]   { variant: 'danger' }
[dev:11ty  ]   ^, file:./src/index.liquid, line:2
[dev:11ty  ]
[dev:11ty  ] `RenderError` was thrown
[dev:11ty  ] > invalid syntax at line 1 col 1:
[dev:11ty  ]
[dev:11ty  ]   { variant: 'danger' }
[dev:11ty  ]   ^
[dev:11ty  ]
[dev:11ty  ] `Error` was thrown:
[dev:11ty  ]     Error: invalid syntax at line 1 col 1:
[dev:11ty  ]
[dev:11ty  ]       { variant: 'danger' }
[dev:11ty  ]       ^
[dev:11ty  ]         at Lexer._token (/Users/Workspace/app/node_modules/moo/moo.js:533:13)
[dev:11ty  ]         at Lexer.next (/Users/Workspace/app/node_modules/moo/moo.js:480:19)
[dev:11ty  ]         at Function.parseArguments (/Users/Workspace/app/node_modules/@11ty/eleventy/src/Engines/Liquid.js:107:23)
[dev:11ty  ]         at Object.render (/Users/Workspace/app/node_modules/@11ty/eleventy/src/Engines/Liquid.js:177:33)
[dev:11ty  ]         at Object._callee$ (/Users/Workspace/app/node_modules/liquidjs/dist/liquid.common.js:1851:55)
[dev:11ty  ]         at tryCatch (/Users/Workspace/app/node_modules/liquidjs/dist/liquid.common.js:108:40)
[dev:11ty  ]         at Generator.invoke [as _invoke] (/Users/Workspace/app/node_modules/liquidjs/dist/liquid.common.js:319:22)
[dev:11ty  ]         at Generator.prototype.<computed> [as next] (/Users/Workspace/app/node_modules/liquidjs/dist/liquid.common.js:156:21)
[dev:11ty  ]         at step (/Users/Workspace/app/node_modules/liquidjs/dist/liquid.common.js:25:30)
[dev:11ty  ]         at /Users/Workspace/app/node_modules/liquidjs/dist/liquid.common.js:43:14
```

Comment: Your example only works in Nunjucks and not Liquid, becuse Nunjucks has [object literals](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/templating.html#expressions) while [Liquid does not](https://shopify.github.io/liquid/basics/types/). So `{ variant: 'danger' }` isn't valid syntax in Liquid — by design. One of the reasons I prefer Nunjucks over Liquid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. In my `_data` folder I added `options.js` file with the following:

```json
{
  "alert1": {
    "variant": "danger"
  }
}
```

Then in my liquid template I passed:

```
{% alert options.alert1 %}
   danger alert
{% endalert %}
```